# How to play back web performance test that uses cookies?

Tags: .net, cookies, performance-testing

I am using .NET Web Performance Test and recorded a short test on a .NET web application that uses forms authentication along with a home grown cookie based process.  The initial request predictably gets a 302 redirect to login successfully.  The subsequent requests needs the cookie values sent on the previous response and that is not happening.

I do see that the cookie for the session being captured and added automatically, but I need the same on home grown values.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to describe the test suite (eg JMeter, HP Load Runner, Visual Studio, etc). Do you know the required cookie values or how to find them? Is you question just asking how to add a new cookie?

Comment: Thanks for looking AdrianHHH.  I am one day into Web Performance Testing and can't find a lot of documentation on how to customize the environment for a test that relies (too heavily) on cookies.  I am exploring creating a Plugin but that is trial and error for me.

Comment: .NET is a library, it is used by  many test suites. Which test suite are you using?

Comment: "Web Performance Test".  I created a Coded UI Test Project and then added a "Web Performance Test...".  I am using Visual Studio 2015.